# How to programmatically segue from searchbar to display screen

Tags: swift, xcode

So I have recently coded a search bar programmatically using tableview and navigation control.  I am now having trouble finding information on how to segue the search bar after the user clicks on an item in the search bar.

I have tried using a view controller but that has not worked.  I think my best bet is to do it programmatically.

**EDIT** There is no function yet in this code to implement a display screen.  Im wondering what code is needed (im a very new developer) to get to another screen after clicking an element in the search bar.  anything helps!!***

```
import UIKit

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    let tableData = ["Boston University", "Boston College", "Northeastern University", "Suffolk University", "American University", "Harvard University", "Massachusetts Institute of Technology", "Tufts University", "Berklee College of Music", "Emerson College"]

    //variables added for search function
    var filteredArray = [String()]
    var shouldShowSearchResults = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createSearcherBar()


    }

    func createSearcherBar() {


        searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = false
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search College"
        searchBar.delegate = self

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredArray = tableData.filter({ (names: String) -> Bool in
            return names.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            })

        if searchText != "" {
            shouldShowSearchResults  = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
        else{
            shouldShowSearchResults = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }


    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if shouldShowSearchResults {
            return filteredArray.count
        }
        else{

            return tableData.count
        }



    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basicCell", for: indexPath)

        if shouldShowSearchResults {
            cell.textLabel!.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }



    }

    override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Hopefully I can get a user to click on one of the options in a search bar, and it brings them to a different page.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Could you explain what specifically isn't working in your code (i.e. only show the specific bit of code relevant to your question) and the behaviour that currently happens?

Comment: Have you implemented the "didSelectRowAt" delegate from the tableView? I don't see in the code you're sharing, so maybe you are missing that one, inside that delegate you can implement your logic to segue to a different view

Comment: hello!! so no part of my code isn't working, im just wondering what I should add to my code that will allow my to get to a different display screen after a user clicks on an item in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your method `textDidChange` is unnecessarily expensive because you are always filtering the array even if the search text is empty. This is more efficient

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {   

    if searchText.isEmpty {
        shouldShowSearchResults = false
        filteredArray.removeAll() // good practice to release memory when the search is finished
    } else {
        filteredArray = tableData.filter{ $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Second of all the declaration of `filteredArray` is slightly wrong. The parentheses must be outside the brackets. Your syntax declares a string array containing one empty string.

```
var filteredArray = [String]()
```

---

To answer your question implement `didSelectRowAt` and add the same `shouldShowSearchResults` logic to distinguish the arrays. Call `performSegue` and pass the string as `sender`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = shouldShowSearchResults ? filteredArray[indexPath.row] : tableData[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "MyIdentifier", sender: item)
}
```

and get it in `prepare(for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "MyIdentifier" else { return }
    let destinationController = segue.destination as! MyViewController
    let item = sender as! String
    ...
```